# angular set form data for all fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I am still new in angular, I don't know how to make form when I want to update user to fill the form with his own data. I have controller like this:

```
        // take data for organization from database            
        dataService.allOrganization().then(function (data) {
            vm.allOrg = data;
        });
        // take data for user from database
        dataService.getOneUser(theId).then(function(data) {
            vm.oneUserUpdate = data;

        });

        $scope.user = {};
        $scope.submitForm = function(theId) {
            $scope.user.idUser = theId;
            dataService.updateUserPost($scope.user).then(function (data) {
                vm.oneUserInfo = data;//response from http request
            })
        }
```

And in view:

```
<form name="userForm" ng-submit="submitForm(userDataCtr.oneUserUpdate.identities[0].user_id)">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Encryption Key :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="encryption" ng-model="user.encryption" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Admin :</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="admin" ng-model="user.admin">
                    <option>Select...</option>
                    <option value="true">True</option>
                    <option value="false">False</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Organization ID:</label>
                <select class="form-control" name="organization" ng-model="user.organization">
                    <option>Select...</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="org in userDataCtr.allOrg" value="{{org.id_org}}">
                        {{org.name_org}}
                    </option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label></label>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="role_cro" ng-model="user.role_cro">ROLE_CRO</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="role_client" ng-model="user.role_client">ROLE_CLIENT</label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

And how, if is possible, to fill all data with user data, input field to have value, checkbox to be checked if they need, select option of organization to be selected, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You want the user to fill all the fields before submitting? you want validations right?

Comment: No, I want to fields be automatically filled when you want to update user, and then to change data if I want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update models. eg

```
dataService.getOneUser(theId).then(function(data) {
        vm.user={};
        vm.user.encryption = data.encryption;
        vm.user.role_client = data.role;
    });
```

On view

```
<div ng-controller="Mycontroller as my">
<div class="form-group">
                <label>Encryption Key :</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="encryption" ng-model="my.user.encryption" >
</div>
</div>
```

And so on... you have to use in your controller instance on your view.

Comment: I changed, but got error that $scope is not defined.

Comment: I think u r not using $scope,u r using var vm=this ?,if so replace $scope from vm in my code,i m editing it too.

Comment: I am using both, for all data I am using vm, only for form validation I am using $scope.

Comment: I got error "vm is not defined", I define var vm = this and then got error "Cannot set property 'encryption' of undefined".

Comment: ok so u have to write first line of ur controller as,var vm=this,then in ur getoneuser function write,vm.user={};vm.user.encryption =data.encryption ,see my code

Comment: I did that vm.user={};vm.user.encryption = data.encryption; and I print in console to check value and it is ok, but in input field still nothing changed <input type="text" class="form-control" name="encryption" ng-model="user.encryption">

Comment: Define ng-controller="yourcontroller as alias" and ng-model="alias.user.encryption" ,see my view code pls

Comment: I did, and I got semi-success, input field for encryption is ok, and select for admin. But select for organization is not selected, and also check box is not checked even I got good value in console and in form submit.

Comment: So u got the basic idea how it working right?you can use the same concept for all :) ,well done .Please upvote for a good cause :)

Comment: I will upvote ;). Can you help me just more with these check box?

Comment: Ok,create a separate question for this after upvoting this one ;),i will definitely do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to use data from a controller (or directive) inside a template, it has to be bound to the controller's $scope.

```
.controller('myFormController', function () {

    dataService.allOrganization().then(function (data) {
        // Populate our scope the required data
        $scope.allOrg = data;
    });
});
```

Now we can bind these variables to our form fields using ng-model.
`<input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="allOrg.firstName">`

Not all form elements behave the same. You should take a look at the angular docs for more in depth examples of form binding.
[Angular form documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms)

Comment: but if I change name for model how I will got all data from form where submit? I put in name for ng-model user.etc and in that way I take all data.